# TeXworks $ problem

Tags: math-mode

This reports me

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\author{Jane Doe}
\date{June 2011}

\begin{document}

\begin{math}

\end{math}

\end{document}
```

Why?

Comment: Your document is empty. What does it report? Most likely 0 pages as output.

Comment: yes it is empty.

Comment: @Werner it reports an error message involving `$` hence the question title :-)

Answer (score 3):

`\begin{math}` is inline math (like `$` ... `$` ) and you may not have a paragraph break (blank line) in a math environment.

Comment: What tag i can use to have blank lines in math statements?

Comment: well basically you can't. You can have a comment there, so put `%` at the beginning of the line.